# How to set always default value for first record in list view in aspx page?

Tags: asp.net

I have an aspx page that uses a simple form to perform a search and the results are presented in a listview.

I have added a radio button to one of the columns and have set the value to be the records FlightNo. set always default value for first record in list view.

What I need to do is allow the user to select the row they require from the list view by selecting the radio button.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "GroupName" property of the radio button control to make the dynamic radio buttons work as a group.  You can add some client script to select the row on 'click'.